# Detect support for CSS property with CSS only

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, mobile-safari

## Short question

Using CSS only, how do I detect that the [background-size](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) property is supported? If it's not supported, I would like to provide some fallback CSS. I already know how to do this with Javascript, but it's cleaner with CSS.

## Long question

I have a high resolution sprite image that needs to look good on all cell phones, regardless of its exact pixel density. By using a [background-size trick](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/high-res-sprites), I can scale the sprite appropriately.

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url(sprite180x76.png);
    /* 180 / 2 = 90 */
    background-size: 90px auto; 
}
```

There are some iOS and Android versions that [don't support the background-size property](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size), so the sprite would look twice as big as it should be. For these old systems, I would like to load up a low resolution sprite with no background scaling:

```
/* fake CSS */
@notSupported(background-size) 
    .sprite {
        background-image: url(sprite90x38.png);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your link, the new background properties (including background-size) are fully supported as far back as iOS 4.0 and Android 2.1. Are you really going to have many (any?) users on operating systems that are older than that? It's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: There's 1 guy in the office that is using iOS 3.1.3 and he will not approve of the website until the site looks good on his phone.

Comment: Is he using an original iPhone then? I believe even an iPhone 3G can be upgraded to iOS 4. Try explaining that because he's using a 5-year-old phone, it simply can't support what you're trying to do...

Comment: [@supports rule](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-conditional/#annotation_at-supports)

Answer (score 3):

CSS doesn't have conditional statements as it's not a programming language like Javascript.  Although, I believe there might be some kind of conditional statement in the works for CSS.

You'll have to rely on JavaScript to achieve any kind of conditional test case for CSS.

Meaning, you can't directly detect support for CSS.

However, CSS does have a "trick" thanks to its "Cascading" nature, but it's only usable when looking to replace some older code with newer code for the same style.

That sounds funny, here's a couple of examples:

```
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-ms-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
```

In browsers that do support the official CSS, it will the style as denoted on line 5.  While in older versions of say Firefox, line 1 will get applied and line 2-5 will get ignored because they're unknown.

Another (and perhaps better) example could be:

```
background-color: #AAA;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

This code will give the background a grey color, while newer browsers will give it a black color with a 50% transparency, overriding the old color.

Hope that helps a little.

Cheers!

-- Update --

I did just come across something that might help.  In Aaron Gustafson's book "Adaptive Web Design" he mentions how CSS will ignore an entire rule if a given browser/renderer doesn't support a given selector.

With the concept above, if you can find a selector that was not implemented in the older version but is available in the newer version you could do something like this:

```
/* fake CSS */
.sprite {
   background-image: url(sprite90x38.png);
}

[[ selector that is supported by newer browser/OS ]],
.sprite {
     background-image: url(sprite180x76.png);
     /* 180 / 2 = 90 */
     background-size: 90px auto; 
}
```

The idea is that for the "old" browsers you can load the old PNG but for the newer browser it will load the larger PNG and apply background size.

The only thing I would be concerned about is if this causes the supportive browsers to load both images but apply one.

And this still requires finding an unsupported selector in one version of another.  Quicksmode.com might help you find one:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

-- UPDATE 2 --

I put this in the comments but I'll add it here as it might help.  I spent some time trying to find out what browser version iOS 3.1.3 supported and therefor what selectors might be possible to use with the above trick.

What I found was this Apple developers site: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

If you do a page search (ctr+f) for background-size, it shows that iOS 1+ supported a proprietary version called:

```
-webkit-background-size: length
-webkit-background-size: length_x length_y
```

That might be a possible solution.  If you add that before the real one, you can ensure backwards compatability.

```
 -webkit-background-size: length
 background-size: length
```

Hopefully that helps find alternate solutions since the original question of doing a conditional test to see if a rule is supported is not possible in CSS right now.

Comment: ... but that's also a little irrelevant unless you provide an example pertaining to the question...

Comment: @Fozzyyuw : in your example, all browsers will show the larger sprite because all browsers understand `background-image`. The latter `background-image` rule overrides the former identical rule.

Comment: @JoJo you're missing the key point of finding a selector that a browser does not support.  This "trick" has been used to target older IE browsers such as the attribute selector "[foo], .sprite{ /* rules */ }" will only render in browsers that support the attribute selector "[foo]" and because this unsupported selector is tied via the comma, it will cause that whole rule to be ignored by say IE 6.  In my example, the idea would be to give the "small" sprite to all browsers but then give the big sprite with background-size to all browsers that can support a special selector.

Comment: The trick is to see if you can also find an unsupported selector in the same browser/OS that doesn't support "background-size" rule.  This lets you do a sort of 1:1 trick thanks to how CSS ignores whole rule blocks for unsupported selectors.  I admit that it might not be possible if there are no unsupported selectors that can map to the "background-size" rule.  It might take some trial/error.

Comment: This concept is used here: http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=062/062.css  IE6 renders differently.  This trick gets harder to use as browsers get better support but there might be something still available.  Unfortunately in this case, the CSS rules don't stop parsing a rule set if it discovers a bad selector.  Otherwise, you could use this trick concept inside a rule block too.

Comment: Have you tried the proprietary tag? "-webkit-background-size: 90px auto".  You can then put that before the standard "background-size: 90px auto;".  That way, full support will override the proprietary tag.  Maybe that will help?  I got that from here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html do a page find for "background-size".  It says it's supported in iOS 1.0+.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (for now) detect support of property A and, given or not this support, serve different values for property B with CSS only ...

... except if the browser support for properties A and B is exactly the same! Then instructions below:

```
selector {
    propertyA: valueA;
    propertyB: valueB;
}
```

will both fail or both succeed.

The remaining problem is to find a CSS property that has the exact same support than `background-size` :)
I was thinking about **`multi-background`** : it should (not) work in IE6/7/8 according to [CSS Background Properties support in Standardista](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/) but I can't test in iOs and Android, only in bada/Dolfin 2.0 (Samsung Wave; also based on Webkit).

Here's a Fiddle : [**http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/2VaWu/**](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/2VaWu/) 
that shows a paragraph with only a simple background that any browser should display and then another paragraph with both a simple background and (*) a multi-background resized with `background-size` that only modern browsers should display (older browsers should display the same background as for the first paragraph).
Fx9 and dolfin 2.0 both display correctly the second paragraph. IE8 doesn't, as expected.

Another solution would be to use a selector understood by browser versions that also understand `background-size` but not understood by others. Though it's easier to find for IE than for smartphones based on Webkit!

(*) using a different CSS rule with higher specificity, for the purpose of the demo. In real world, there'd be only one rule with simple background defined before the multiple background.